# Code going through laravel basic authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

Ok so I'm half way trough my app and I notice that I can pass code into my database. For example I use standard laravel authentication and if I type e.g.`<?php die(); ?>` instead of first name it passes right trough and goes into database. I'm confused now , I tought that laravel takes care of those things and thats one of the reasons I chose this framework. This is my last resort, I have been searching something in laravel documentation and all over the web about this and I found nothing.

Register Controller:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'role' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'gendre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'country' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:15'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:100', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'gendre'=>$data['gendre'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'company' => $data['company'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname' , 'email','password', 'company', 'phone','country','role','gendre'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I only did some minor changes to what laravel already provides, nothing that special.

And Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('role');
            $table->string('gendre');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i understand well you are sending from your form: `<?php die(); ?>` to your laravel backend?

Comment: I took that code as an example , any code that I write goes trough every input field. But yeah

Comment: Can you share your backend code please?

Comment: What is you Laravel version?

Comment: Laravel Framework 7.22.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there may be a little bit of confusion going on here!

---

**SQL Injection Attacks**

The Laravel framework uses things like prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection Attacks. The stops things like

```
"; DELETE FROM `users`"
```

being appended to a database query when inserting data provided by form requests.

---

**Escaping Rendered Characters**

Trying to render content into a blade template will also be escaped by default unless you explicitly tell it otherswise

```
# $php_code = "<?php die(); ?>"
{{ $php_code }}
```

This will render as a a string of "".

```
# $php_code = "<?php die(); ?>"
{!! $php_code !!}
```

This will render the php and stop the script from running

---

**TLDR;**

The fact the the input is "`<?php die(); ?>`" is fine provided it is treated as a string. At the end of the day, It's just a string of valid characters

Comment: Most certanly is cause I am confused as hell. What you are telling me is that it can do no harm even if a user registers as a piece of code as long as it goes trough validation as a string?

Comment: Essesntially yes, that string would only be a threat if it were ever to be evaluated as PHP rather than a string. For example, maybe you want to display an article on your website that contained a `<code></code>` element such as the ones shown in a stackoverflow question like this. You would need to store "'<?php die(); ?>'" as a string and the render it as a string in that code block for everyone to see ;).

Comment: If you are concerned about someone using "dodgy" characters in a username, consider adding something like `alpha_num` validation to the request for the username input. (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: I went trough whole documentation on validation before I posted the question so I have seen all possible arguments, thanks tho. I was experimenting and was expecting to see some escaped strings instead of clean code in my database, hence my confusion